# Is there anything special to consider when writing my own exception class in C++?

Tags: c++, exceptions

If I wanted to implement my own version of the std::exception for no good reason, are there any special things about implementing this kind of object that I should be aware of? It seems like a fairly simple thing that is mostly a string wrapper...

Here is my implementation so far:

```
#pragma once;

#include <string>

class MyException
{
public:
    MyException(const std::wstring&);
    virtual ~MyException(){}

    virtual MyException& operator=(const MyException& rhs);
    virtual const std::wstring& what(){return msg;};

private:
    std::wstring msg;
};

MyException::MyException(const std::wstring& message)
:msg(message)
{
}

MyException& MyException::operator=(const MyException& rhs)
{
    if(this == &rhs)
    {
        return *this;
    }
    msg = rhs.msg;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: How is this off-topic?

Answer (score 4):

The best advice I could give you is to base your code on the [standard exception classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception). It will make your code simpler and will allow you and your users to interact with existing code, the standard library or third party libraries.

Comment: They can't handle Unicode, whereas my direct guess would be that he's using VS and wants to deal with Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

Not particularly. Exception handling is already an expensive routine, so it's difficult to cock things up from that perspective, and the language doesn't treat thrown objects notably different to any other. In fact, you could simply throw a string if you wanted to. But you should design the more derived classes to contain more information, IMO.